# Will Blender files saved on a Windows version of Blender, work on a Linux version of Blender?

Tags: workflow, system

I am building a new PC and considering installing a Linux distro rather than Windows.  I am concerned that the files that I saved on my Windows PC will not be able to load onto a Linux version of Blender.  Could I use Wine and use the Windows versions of my software for better compatibility?  I have read that Blender runs better on Linux.  Any advice welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, the Blender files will work no matter what OS you saved them on

Answer (score 7):

It does not matter if you save it at Windows, Mac or Linux. A blend file is a blend file. Important is the Blender version. Blend files that are saved with the same version of Blender opens in Blender, regardless at which platform.

Wine is not necessary nor recommended. Blender runs natively at Linux. It would just add another software layer that would slow Blender down.

If it makes sense to use Linux is your personal decision. Blender itself runs on all platforms.

Comment: just a small remark to Tiles right answer: a blend file just consists of the "settings" of the scene in his "own" Blender-format. Just the Blender executables (.exe in windows, .app on mac ...) are different and platform specific.